# JavaScript - "forEach is not a function" inside fetch().then(); refuses to be converted to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

so, I have made use of the fetch API to...

1. get a JSON File off my local server
2. insert the contents into a  element, with appropriate Values, etc. (currently Non-Functional, but also not relevant)

**The JSON File:** roughly like this: `[["hello.css", "world.css", "why.css"], "doesn't.css", "this.css", "work.css"]`

**The Conditions:** if there is a big Group of Strings in an array, inside the array, then turn that into a <optgroup>.

**Where it Fails:** in the Initialization of the first forEach function.

### **What I have found out:**

- The Recieved Text is treated as an Object, obiously making it fail.
- It also fails to convert it into an array. Either it is empty or fails differently. Look further below for my attempts.
- It is already parsed, apperently, because with JSON.parse it throws an error, complaining about it.

### **The Code**

```js
fetch('./themes.json').then(theResponse => {
    let themesJSON = theResponse.text();
    console.log(themesJSON); /* All "console.log()" functions are for debugging purposes */
    themesJSON.forEach(elm => {
        let the = '';
        if (elm.length > 1) {
            let optgroup = document.createElement('optgroup');
            elm.forEach(elm => {
                let opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = elm;
                opt.innerText = elm;
                optgroup.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', opt);

                console.log(opt);
            })
            the.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", optgroup)

            console.log(optgroup);
        } else {
            let opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = elm;
            opt.innerText = elm;
            the.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', opt);

            console.log(opt);
        }
        document.getElementById('themeSelection').insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", the);
        console.log(the);
    });
})
```

### The Attempts

- [This Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606849), returns an empty array, and is not an object anymore, i think
- [Another Answer under the same post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750755), exact same result.
- [whatever this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970020/19701713), only tried the first option, as the other one, well, I didn't fully understand it, result? I don't recall anymore.

Comment: `theResponse.json()` (or `.text()`) returns a Promise. You might want to add an additional `.then(res => res.json())` before your current `then`, and use `theResponse` as-is (no more `.text()`, `.json()` or `JSON.parse()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using:

`let themesJSON = theResponse.text();`

which returns a promise that resolves to a string.

What you need is JavaScript representation of your JSON file.

For that the correct syntax would be like this:

```
fetch('./themes.json')
.then(theResponse => theResponse.json())
.then(actualArray => {
    console.log(actualArray)
})
```